# R programming dbconnect

Tags: r

I am running R in ubuntu with MySQL. I installed the RMySQL package and I'm trying to establish a connection to my database, but I get the following error 'Error: could not find function "dbConnect"'. How can i  install the  dbconnect package into R?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You need R library `DBI`; according to [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html):

> Version:  0.10.14
>   Depends:    R (≥ 2.8.0), DBI (≥ 0.4)

So

```
install.packages("DBI")
```

should fix the problem.

Comment: R version 3.8.0  DBI version 0.8, I have included the DBI library also

Comment: @KalpanaVenkateswaran And? `library(DBI)` should fix your `dbConnect` issue. Does it?